# How to override UpgradeData.php with Factory?

Tags: magento2, overrides, factory, preference

I need to override the **UpgradeData** Class from `Catalog\Setup\UpgradeData`
But the constructor has factories in his arguments like
**CategorySetupFactory**

When I run `setup:di:compile` I got an error that this class does not exists.
How can I then override that class or one of its functions at least?

Comment: I'm curious about the reason why you want to override the upgrade data class?

Comment: I have the problem that the new update to 2.1.6 cant use setup:upgrade because there is a problem with attribute_id. There is also a fix for this class but I cant override it.

Answer (score 0):

Factory classes have only 1 function, namely `create` and its only purpose is to return a new instance of a class they are factory of, so `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategorySetupFactory` will return an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategorySetup`. If you require some specific changes to that class create a preference for that class.